# Is there a way to output the contents of the queue after removing an item?

Tags: python, queue

I'm just working on writing code for queues (specifically linear ones) and I'm trying to remove an item from my queue. When outputting the queue after removing an item, the contents in the queue have not changed and all the items are still there. Is there any way to get around this?

I've tried printing out the queue after each item has been removed and still, the output does not change.

```py
import sys
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = 0
        self.MaxSize = 4 
        self.queue = []

    def size(self):
        return self.tail - self.head

    def enqueue(self,data):
        if self.size() > self.MaxSize:
            return("Queue Full")

        else:
            self.queue.append(data)
            self.tail += 1
            return True

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.size() <= 0:
            self.reset()
            return("Queue Empty")
        data = self.queue[self.head]
        self.head += 1
        return data

    def reset(self):
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = 0
        self.queue = []

q = Queue()
def addOrRemove():
    print("Current Queue Size - ", q.size())
    print()
    addRemove = input("Add(A), Remove(R), End(E), View(V) ")
    addRemove = addRemove.upper()
    while True:
        if addRemove == 'A':
            add = input("Enter input - ")
            q.enqueue(add)
            if q.size() > q.MaxSize:
                print("Queue Full")
            addOrRemove()
        elif addRemove == 'R':
            q.dequeue()
            print(q.queue)
            if q.size() <= 0:
                print("Queue Empty")
                q.reset()
            addOrRemove()
        elif addRemove == 'E':
            sys.exit()
        elif addRemove == 'V':
            print(" ".join(q.queue))
            addOrRemove()
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
            addOrRemove()
            return False
addOrRemove()
```

Add 'milk', 'sugar' and 'eggs' to the queue. Removing an item should remove 'milk' and printing the queue should output 'sugar' and 'eggs', but the actual output is still 'milk', 'sugar' and 'eggs'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here isn't your printing, it's your queue. Look at your `dequeue()` method:

```
def dequeue(self):
    if self.size() <= 0:
        self.reset()
        return("Queue Empty")
    data = self.queue[self.head]
    self.head += 1
    return data
```

At no point are you *removing* anything from `self.queue`, so naturally when you try to print it it'll not have changed.

The solution here, is instead of

```
data = self.queue[self.head]
```

which is itself a logic error (what if there are only 3 elements in `self.queue` and `self.head == 5`? You'd get an error), do

```
data = self.queue.pop(0)
```

which *removes the first element* from `self.queue` and returns it. Since in `enqueue()` you're adding to the *end* of the list and in `dequeue()` you'll be removing from the *beginning* of the list, it's a valid queue.